# Powershell - Display value of an object's properties, where the property names are like '*quota*'

Tags: powershell

As per the subject, I'm trying to get the name of a property and the value assocaited with that property, for a specific mailbox.

So, the line below gets me a nice list of the available object properties, and a default column displayed in the output has the heading 'Name'

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity "Person Name" | gm
```

I then want to say something like:

1. For the object: "Mailbox of Person Name"
2. Where the property of "Mailbox of Person Name" has a name like '*quota*'
3. List both the actual property name and it's value for "Mailbox of Person Name"

I've tried a number of things using -ExpandProperty/Select-Object/Where-Object but they're all failing. I'm sure this is pretty basic, but Powershell is definitely not my strength. Can anyone show me how to structure this pipeline correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `Where-Object`, only `Select-Object`:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity "Person Name" | Select-Object -Property *quota*
```

Comment: Wow, that is amazingly simple, thanks!
I had this horrible suspicion that I had over complicated as well. I still struggle to a degree with the 'object' pipeline of powershell vs the 'textual' pipeline of other shells like Bash etc.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have used the correct commandlets. `Where-Object` filters. `Select-Object` selects specific properties.

From my experience, sometimes what you see on the console doesn't match the actual property name because there is a formatter that can even change the column name. If you you drive the `Where-Object` and `Select-Object` with that virtual property name then they do fail. Also sometimes, the output is not really a recordset that works well with these cmdlets.

My advice is to always check the type of an object when things go strange. Starting from `$items=Get-Mailbox -Identity "Person Name"`.
Then `$items.GetType()` reveals the actual .net type.
Then `$items.Count` reveals if it is actually an array or a single object.
Then `$items|ForEach-Object {$_.GetType()}` reveals the type of each object.

Also the `$items|Get-Member` is very helpful to figure out the property names. If necessary use it also within your loop.

That is how I troubleshoot strange behaviors and if you can post your findings and the code you tried with `Where-Object` and `Select-Object` that would be a great help.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance Alex, greatly appreciated. Fortunately, Moshe Perez below has nailed it (quite elegantly might I add). The lesson is the same as ever in tech and computing, check the basics thoroughly before going for the doomsday/fancy theories!

Again though, your advice is excellent and I appreciate your feedback on a structured approach for solving these sorts of issues myself. Cheers.