# Powershell get only properties matching string pattern from Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I was trying to get all properties containing the string "home" from an AD User (HomeDirectory, HomeDrive etc.). I can make that work by doing the following based off of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361884/powershell-display-value-of-an-objects-properties-where-the-property-names-a):

```
Get-ADUser -Identity MyUser -Properties * | Select-Object -Property "*home*"
```

However, this will bog down the system if I'm doing it in a for-loop since it will fetch *all properties* first, and then after that filter out the ones that match the string "home" anywhere in the property name.

Is there a way to do this filtering already in the Get-ADUser call to reduce the amount of information being sent? I guess the more generic question would be: is there a way in Powershell to fetch only properties of an object that matches a specific string pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this pattern yourself by calling `get-aduser -id myuser -properties * | % { $_.propertynames -match "home" }` - doing this ONCE you can store the outcome into an array then supply this to further `get-aduser` calls.

```
$proplist=get-aduser -id myuser -properties * | % { $_.propertynames -match "home" }
get-aduser -properties $proplist
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines and a colleague of mine suggested the same thing. I think I have to concede that this is the solution I have to roll with but I don't like it as it feels like a hacky workaround. What if I'm using a different variable/object, will I need to hardcode one object for them too? It doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that I will have to roll with this. I don't like settling, I would prefer if I could find a more generic solution that works for other commandlets or objects where I don't know what the properties of the object are.

Comment: So, you have troubles in settling for a hardcoded "myuser" constant in the script? Hmm...  you can at least run `get-aduser` without any parameters and get first user as the user to query for full parameters. Also you can use a user environmental variable to store that user name if you have done the discovery.

Comment: I think my issue is not really having to run specifically Get-ADUser but rather knowing one existing object. If I do a similar thing with $MyProperties = (Get-Service | gm | ?{$_.Name -like "*Name*"}).Name, then I can use $MyProperties with Get-Service | Select-Object $MyProperties. In this case, I don't need to know the name of a running service to get the properties that I'm interested in. I'm looking for this kind of generic solution for finding properties matching a specific string for any type of object, without knowing an existing object.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to first get an array of all LDAP attribute names from the AD Schema:

```
function Get-ADUserAttributeNames {
    # First, get all AD user attributes defined in the Active Directory schema
    $searchBase    = (Get-ADRootDSE).SchemaNamingContext
    $schemaAttribs = (Get-ADObject -SearchBase $searchBase -Filter "name -like 'user'" -Properties MayContain,SystemMayContain |
                     Select-Object @{Name = 'Attribs'; Expression = {$_.maycontain + $_.systemmaycontain}}).Attribs

    # Next, get all created user attributes. These are not defined in the schema, but calculated when asked for
    $flagsAttribs = (Get-ADObject -SearchBase $searchBase -LDAPFilter '(systemFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=4)' -Properties systemFlags).Name

    return ($schemaAttribs + $flagsAttribs) | Sort-Object
}
$userAttribs = Get-ADUserAttributeNames
```

In subsequent calls, use the returned $userAttribs array like this:

```
$homeAttribs = $userAttribs | Where-Object { $_ -like '*home*' }
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $homeAttribs
```

---

**Some explanation**

This approach retrieves the list of **LDAP** user attribute names from the AD Schema itself, so there is no need to probe a known user. The returned attribs apply to *any* user object in your AD environment.

With [Vesper's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65069533/9898643) you **do** need a user that you know exists, but that's no problem of course since you can simply use your own SamAccountName.

The reason I've emphasized **LDAP** is that Ldap attribute names are not always as self-descriptive as you would like, sometimes just one character and on other occasions ridiculously long..
That is why PowerShell maps most common atribute names to more friendly (and also case-insensitive) names.

Some examples:

```
LDAP                        PowerShell
----                        ----------
l                           City
o                           Organization
cn                          Name
physicalDeliveryOfficeName  Office
facsimileTelephoneNumber    Fax
wWWHomePage                 HomePage
nTSecurityDescriptor        CannotChangePassword
```

PowerShell in some cases also changes the format of an attribute to an easier to use format like with `Enabled` which returns a Boolean value from computing the LDAP `userAccountControl (bit mask not 2)` or `PasswordLastSet` which returns a DateTime object from ldap's `pwdLastSet` attribute.

The AD Schema can be extended with more attributes. Sometimes software does that (like Exchange that extends the schema with lots of `msExch*` atributes) but you (as administrator) can add new properties too.
The list you get with above function is therefore quite, but not completely static and can change over time.

Comment: Does that not also require me to search for a user that I know exist? As in, the "name -like 'user'" would imply that I need to fetch all properties from a known user, and then use those attributes to filter out the ones that I'm looking for? I probably lack the AD knowledge here but in my eyes this looks like it runs into the same situation that Vesper's suggestion, namely that I need to fetch a known object before looping. It works, I'm just not sold on the idea, I'd love to find a solution that could do the property string matching without knowing how the object will look like.

Comment: @MagneTism for this you do not have to use a known user, because it is getting the property names from the AD Schema itself and returns the possible attributes for _any_ user in your environment. You could get that list anytime and use it in scripts later, but remember that custom attributes can be added by software or yourself, so it _can_ change over time.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you earlier, I will try this out later this week or beginning of next and report back the results.